# Как переместить выделение на только что созданный элемент массива?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Всем привет. Имеется два окна. В первом хранится таблица с пользователями и данными о них, во второй форма для добавления и редактированния этих пользователей.
Не могу придумать, как ставить фокус на вновь добавленный элемент ( выделять его рамочкой в таблице).

Окно с пользователями. Пометил комметарием место где находится функция отвечающая за выделение стилями текущего пользователя ( по которому кликнули).
Думаю, требуется перенести этот функционал в редьюсер, чтобы можно было вызвать во втором окне в момент нажатия на кнопку добавления нового пользователя. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

```
import React from 'react'
import FirstWindowItems from './FirstWindowItems'
import {connect, useDispatch} from "react-redux"
import {createNewUser, userInfo} from "./redux/action"



const FirstWindow = ({items}) =>{
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    function getElem(i, item) {
       setActive(i);  // ТУТ ПРОИСХОДИТ ВЫДЕЛЕНИЯ ТЕКУЩЕЦ СТРОКИ ПО КЛИКУ. Требуется сделать такое же выделение на только что добавленный элемент.
       console.log(items) 
       dispatch(userInfo(item));     // вызываем экшен для поиска активного элемента   
    }
    
    const [active, setActive] = React.useState(null);
    return(
        <div className = "container">
            {
                items.items.map((item,i) =>{
                    return <FirstWindowItems
                     item = {item}
                     isActive={active===i}
                     onClick={()=>getElem(i,item)}
                     key={item.id}
                     
                     ></FirstWindowItems>
                })
            }
            
        </div>
    )
}



const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state.items);
    return {
        items: state.items
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    createNewUser:createNewUser
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FirstWindow);
```

Окно формы для работы с данными пользователей ( изменения, добавление )

```
import { bool } from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import {createNewUser, deleteUser, changeInfo, userInfo} from "../components/redux/action"


class SecondWindow extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
         
    }
    
    
    handleOptionChange = e => {
        this.setState(
            {
                selectedOption:e.target.value
            }
        )
    }

    submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault();        

        const newUser = {
            id: Date.now().toString(),
            FIO: "Имя",
            position:"Должность",
            birthDay: "год/месяц/день",
            sex: true ,
            fired: false
        };
        console.log(this.props);
        this.props.createNewUser(newUser);
        this.props.userInfo(newUser);
    }

    changeInputHandler = ({ target: t }) => {
        this.setState(state => ({
          ...state,
          [t.name]: t.type === 'checkbox' ? t.checked : t.value,
        }));
        

        const valueForUpdate = {
            id: this.props.items.activeUser.id,
            box: t.name,
            newValue: t.type === 'checkbox'  ? t.checked : t.value
        };
        console.log(t.checked)
        this.props.changeInfo(valueForUpdate);
      }

    isFormValid = () => {
        const {FIO, position, birthDay, sex, fired} = this.state;
        console.log(FIO && position && birthDay && sex && fired);
        return FIO && position && birthDay && sex && fired 
    }

    deleteUser = () => {
        this.props.deleteUser(this.props.items.activeUser);
        
    }
    

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <div className="input-group mb-3">                    
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="ФИО"
                    name="FIO" 
                    onChange={this.changeInputHandler}
                    value={this.props.items.activeUser.FIO}
                    ></input>
                </div>
                <select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"
                name ="position"
                onChange={this.changeInputHandler}
                value={this.props.items.activeUser.position}> 
                    <option defaultValue = "Выбирите должность">Выбирите должность</option>       
                    <option value="Старший разработчик">Старший разработчик</option>
                    <option value="Младший разработчик">Младший разработчик</option>
                    <option value="Эйчар">Эйчар</option>
                    <option value="Уборщик">Уборщик</option>
                </select>

                <div className="form-group ">                
                    <div className="mb-3"></div>
                        <input className="form-control" type="date"  id="example-date-input"
                        name ="birthDay"
                        onChange={this.changeInputHandler}
                        value={this.props.items.activeUser.birthDay}></input>  
                </div>
              


               
                <div className="form-check">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault"
                     id="flexRadioDefault1"
                     value = {true}
                     name ="sex"
                     onChange={this.changeInputHandler}
                     checked={this.props.items.activeUser.sex ? true : false }
                    ></input>
                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexRadioDefault1">
                    М
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-check">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault"
                    id="flexRadioDefault1"
                    value = {false}
                    name ="sex"
                    onChange={this.changeInputHandler}
                    checked={!this.props.items.activeUser.sex ? true : false}
                    ></input>
                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexRadioDefault1">
                    Ж
                    </label>
                
                </div>

                
                
                <div className="form-check">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  id="flexCheckDefault"
                    name ="fired"
                    onChange={this.changeInputHandler}
                    checked={this.props.items.activeUser.fired}
                    ></input>
                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexCheckDefault">
                    Уволен
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick = {this.submitHandler}
                 disabled = {!this.isFormValid}
                 >Добавить нового сотрудника</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger"
                 onClick = {this.deleteUser}>Удалить выбранного сотрудника</button>  
            </form>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state.items.items);
    return {
        items: state.items,

    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    createNewUser: createNewUser,
    deleteUser:deleteUser,
    changeInfo:changeInfo,
    userInfo: userInfo
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SecondWindow);
```

Редьюсер

```
import { object } from 'prop-types'
import {CREATE_NEW_USER, DELETE_USER, USER_INFO, CHANGE_INFO} from './types'

const initialState = {
    items: [
        {id:1, FIO: "Шнуров В.А", position:"Старший разработчик", birthDay: "1998-05-13", sex: true, fired: false},
        {id:2, FIO: "Теркин А.А", position:"Младший разработчик", birthDay: "1972-03-14", sex: true, fired: false},
        {id:3, FIO: "Смолин У.В", position:"Эйчар",birthDay: "1956-07-22", sex: true, fired: true},
        {id:4, FIO: "Шарапова З.Е", position:"Уборщик",birthDay: "1923-07-22", sex: false, fired: false},
    ],
    activeUser: {}
}


const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CREATE_NEW_USER:            
            return {...state, items: state.items.concat([action.payload])}
        
        case DELETE_USER:
            return {...state, items: state.items.filter((item)=>{
                return item.id !== action.payload.id;
            })
        }
        case USER_INFO:
            return {...state, activeUser: action.payload}

        case CHANGE_INFO:
            return {...state, items: state.items.map((item)=>{
                if(item.id === action.payload.id){  
                    console.log(item) 
                    // console.log(action.payload.id, item[action.payload.box], action.payload.newValue);                 
                    item[action.payload.box] = action.payload.newValue;
                    return item
                }
                else return item
            })
        }
       

        default:
            return state;
    }
    
}

export {reducer}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как то так примерно:

```
// тут твой стейт после добавления последнего элемента.
let items = [ { id:1 },{ id:2 },{ id:3 } ]  

// тут ты получаешь последний добавленный элемент
let newTargetItem = items.filter( ( f,i,arr ) => f.id === arr.length )
```

Ну а потом делай с ним чего хочешь: передавай в функцию для выделения, используй в useEffect для выделения после перерисовки, удаляй, редактируй.